# How to avoid "No stages / jobs for this pipeline." in GitLab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I would like to have a flow in GitLab CI where all tests run in merge requests, and once they have passed the branch is merged to `master` with a fast-forward, so there is no need to repeat the same tests again. For this reason commits to `master` may have no jobs associated. For example with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
test:
  script: mytest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

after the merge request passes the test, the pipeline in `master` will fails with `"No stages / jobs for this pipeline."`. This can be verified in the CI Lint page by checking the box `Simulate a pipeline created for the default branch`. Is there a way to prevent the CI from failing in `master` when there are no jobs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) solution might help you:

```yaml
test:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      script:
       - mytest

    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      script: 
       - mytest

      allow_failure: true
```

I hope this solution helps you or at least guide you to find the solution!